# Access to the path is denied when using Directory.GetFiles(...) - in D:\ but CAN call it on D:\Videos

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I am using .NET 4.8  (a bit of a long story as to why, but doesn't matter)

I'm calling:

`ret = Directory.GetFiles (path, searchPattern, searchOptions).ToList();`

Where path is 'D:\', Search Options is SearchOption.AllDirectories, and searchPattern is "*.*"

I get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` (I catch it explicitly) when it runs. Running as an Admin Account. In an Admin cmd window does not help.

If I change it to D:\Videos, it works and gives me all the files in that folder!   Which means that I *must* have access to D:\  - and in fact, in the same command window (this is a command line app), I can do 'dir d:' and it works fine, or d:\

I have an old version of this application, and it runs just fine with the same arguments (no longer have the source code to it, so I rewrote the app recently.)

This is about the first thing that this application does after parsing arguments, so it shouldn't have any side effects of other code.

Only clue I have is the drive is an externally mounted USB SSD, but I don't know how that can matter.

**Note:** Not a duplicate of Access to path is denied when using `Directory.Getfiles` that someone else asked - really, it isn't. This is a different problem using the same call.

Comment: If a string literal, are you using `"D:\"` instead of `"D:\\"` by mistake?  You don't show `path` being initialized.

Comment: Obviously, I'm not using "D:\"   as that would be an unterminated string, and result in a compiler error.   And if I was using "D:\"", I'd have to be aware of the issue and explicitly ignoring it. The issue ended up being that D:\ contained the System Volume Information directory, and even as an Admin on the machine, I didn't have access to look in that directory.  (Per accepted answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you specified SearchOption.AllDirectories, you'll get UnauthorizedAccessException if you don't have permission to access *at least one* subdirectory under D:\ (such as D:\System Volume Information), even if you can access D:\ itself. The exception message should identify this subdirectory.

To avoid this exception, don't use SearchOption.AllDirectories. Instead, enumerate subdirectories using your own recursive method, and skip any subdirectory to which you don't have access.

Answer (score 2):

**In .NET Core and .NET 5+:** You can use the overload which accepts a `EnumerationOptions` and specify `IgnoreInaccessible = true`.

Also note that `GetFiles` is inefficient if you are just going to insert it into a list, it's better to use `EnumerateFiles`.

```cs
ret = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern,
    new EnumerationOptions
    {
        IgnoreInaccessible = true,
        RecurseSubdirectories = true,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, EnumerationOptions isn't available in the .NET Framework.

Comment: True, but I think it's worth a mention still